# Do-notation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to figure out a way to prettify monadic libraries in TypeScript. While the implementation of the monad itself goes pleasantly ahead, its usage looks like the familiar callback hell.

I was wondering if there is a way to hijack the existing monadic syntactic sugar of async/await or yield/for..of, but I must admit I am having some trouble connecting the dots. Is it possible to use these constructs on something that is neither a Promise nor an Iterable, and is as different as a continuation monad composed with react components?

Comment: Can you maybe add some code to show exactly what you mean and give us something to work with?

Comment: I know very little about TypeScript, and little JavaScript, but mayby [this](https://github.com/Risto-Stevcev/do-notation) is portable to TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm limited on time but here's a quick little example using the continuation monad `Cont` as an example

```js
// first: WITHOUT do-notation

const Cont = f => ({
  runCont: f,
  chain: g =>
    Cont(k => f (x => g (x) .runCont (k)))
})

Cont.of = x =>
  Cont(k => k (x))

const result = Cont.of (2) .chain (x =>
  Cont.of (3) .chain (y =>
    Cont.of (x + y)))

result.runCont (console.log)
// 5
```

Now the same thing using a sort of `do`-notation – `do` is a reserved keyword in JS, so I named my function `run`

```js
// second: WITH do-notation

const run = g => {
  const next = x => {
    let {value, done} = g.next (x)
    return done
      ? value
      : value.chain (next)
  }
  return next (null)
}

const Cont = f => ({
  runCont: f,
  chain: g =>
    Cont(k => f (x => g (x) .runCont (k)))
})

Cont.of = x =>
  Cont(k => k (x))

const result = run (function* () {
  let x = yield Cont.of (2)
  let y = yield Cont.of (3)
  return Cont.of (x + y)
} ())

result.runCont (console.log)
// 5
```

---

**warning:** You *could* use `async/await` but then your values get stuck inside of Promises – that'd probably annoying under most circumstances.

Comment: If you really want to rely upon this, you'll want to get some error checking around it – right now it assumes the yielded types have a `chain` method.

Comment: I think generator functions don't work with the list monad. Besides they are stateful and you can't yield inside higher order functions, hence no map/reduce et al. However, I don't know a better way either. But I will think about it.