# flatmap do notation sugar for nested if undefined

Tags: typescript

I have several functions that takes a number and extra parameters, returns a number or undefined.
I want to call these functions sequentially and process the final value of the good path.

How can I avoid nested if statements like below code?

```
export function addPositive(num: number): number | undefined {
    if (num > 0) {
        return num + 2;
    }
}

let four = addPositive(3)

if (four) {
    let five = addPositive(four);

    if (five) {
        let six = addPositive(five);

        console.log(six);
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking to improve working code - ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: I would think you'd want an  `addPositive()`-like function that also accepts `undefined`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m02yOw).  I don't believe there are any optional chaining or nullish coalescing techniques that work like that, so you have to roll your own.  If that answer seems reasonable I'll write it up.  If not, please elaborate on what you're looking for.

Comment: I think that's closest to what I am looking for thanks. But the function I am calling might change except taking parameter number and returning optional number.

Comment: I just saw the comment "the function I am calling might change" so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to use [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to emulate do-notation; there are other questions on Stack Overflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530397/do-notation-in-typescript) you can consult if that's really what you need. But I'd think it would be hard to get the typings correct (you'd want the compiler to know that the `yield` in `let five = yield ap(four)`  had the effect of turning `number | undefined` into just `number`, and I don't see an obvious way to do that).  Even if you could do it, it seems quite heavyweight.

---

In this particular instance, I'd rather roll the `undefined` check into the implementation of `addPositive()` so that it both accepts and returns `number | undefined`. For example:

```
function ap(num: number | undefined) {
    return num ? addPositive(num) : undefined;
}
```

Now you can just pass the result of each call as the argument of the next call without having to resort to something like generators:

```
let four = ap(3)
let five = ap(four);
let six = ap(five);
console.log(six); // 9
```

If you need to use *different functions* and not just `addPositive()`, then you can make a transformer that turns a function of the form `(x: T) => T | undefined` to one of the form `(x: T | undefined) => T | undefined`:

```
const def = <T,>(cb: (x: T) => T | undefined) =>
    (x: T | undefined) =>
        typeof x === "undefined" ? undefined : cb(x);
```

And then the `ap` function above is just

```
let ap = def(addPositive);
```

And behaves the same way:

```
let four = ap(3)
let five = ap(four);
let six = ap(five);
console.log(six); // 9
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoApwM41gNwFMAKMEAWwC5EzyAjQgJwEpraHHEAfRcVQ4DDCFUiAN4AoRNMQxgiUhUQA+RAAZm4qTJ2NCUEIyS1EAakQAmANzbpAX1uI9BozYcTQkWAhQAHRVQ0FBzcvGD8gsKompK6+obGSgD8KOhYuAQktJrUfAJCIm4SEgA2+ojAcIaIALx+xADMzKXlgkS19ZWGzDZlUIi4AB4dyP5thD0SEAjYcGUAdCVwAObEQz2IAPSbiACcxRJgyOSE2L7IEISIAGLgAMIAFshgy1exMtNg2P0RHQA8ABUADTKYgQOjUYiDagAzQ1VQA0J5SIiOHKRw6KEwpHhfJRNEYnQyKAAT18hDg8mGNRpiAARMiCqg6YgUoyoohqOCoZNHH0-B0IsQ0JgcHgYERJjo+a0qpw6qNGs0dPzxiMxnKpTJ+UN1cRxlrpJ9Zgslqt1lYtjt9hI7EA)